# Host no longer supports PHP functions for FTP! Workaround?

Tags: php, ftp

So my host just updated all their hardware and software and they have decided to no longer support any of the PHP FTP functions (ftp_connect, etc).

Anyone know a way around this? Luckily I have classed all my PHP functions so I will only need to build the work around once (If there is one?)

Maybe Upload using fSocket? Any examples / tutorials would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

CURL is a good option.

file_get/put_contents with contexts may also be an option.

Answer (score 1):

FTP is supported with file commands, so you can do this to upload:

`file_put_contents("ftp://user:pass@server/path/to/file.ext", $filecontent);`

See [this page](http://us.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php) for what functions the FTP wrapper supports in PHP 4 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://php-classes.kinghost.net/browse/package/1743.html) looks promising. at least from the description it sounds just like what you're looking for. I didn't try it (as I don't have an account on that site) but it might be worth checking out. Why reinvent the wheel...